# Best way to tell what a .meta:n l3key has been set to

Tags: expl3, l3keys

What is the best way to tell what a `.meta:n` l3key has been set to?

e.g., in the following MWE, how can I tell that `keyc` was set to `true` even if `keya` and `keyb` are subsequently set to `false`?

The best way I can think of is to include a private undocumented key that saves the value of `keyc`, like I've done for `keyd`. Is this my best option or does l3keys have some clever feature I don't know about yet?

In case it helps the goal/use case is that when `keyc` is set:

- the defaults of some keys should change, but they should be able to be overridden
- some keys should conflict and should not be able to be set
- there should be different behaviour of some package internal code not otherwise affected by other keys

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { dcp }
  {
    , keya  .bool_set:N = \l_dcp_keya_bool
    , keyb  .bool_set:N = \l_dcp_keyb_bool
    , keyc  .meta:n     = { keya = #1, keyb = #1 }
    , _keyd .bool_set:N = \l__dcp_keyd_bool
    , keyd  .meta:n     = { _keyd = #1, keya = #1, keyb = #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_set:nn { dcp } { keyc = true, keya = false, keyb = false }
keya: ~ \bool_to_str:N \l_dcp_keya_bool \para_end:
keyb: ~ \bool_to_str:N \l_dcp_keyb_bool \para_end:
keyc: ~ ? \para_end:
\keys_set:nn { dcp } { keyd = true, keya = false, keyb = false }
keya: ~ \bool_to_str:N \l_dcp_keya_bool \para_end:
keyb: ~ \bool_to_str:N \l_dcp_keyb_bool \para_end:
keyd: ~ \bool_to_str:N \l__dcp_keyd_bool \para_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know, but I think I'd consider `keyc` and `keyd` not being set to any particular value, they are "meta", after all. But I presume you have an actual problem you are trying to handle.

Comment: @gusbrs, yes. I added a little detail to the question. I'm not opposed to not using `.meta:n` if it's not the best option.

Comment: By your list, in your place, I'd probably go with a regular `.code:n`. ;-) But perhaps someone has a better idea.